# Value modification inside child doesn't update

Tags: c, linux, shell

Im trying to modify an int inside a child process when fork(); but I cant get the program to update it more than once, my idea is to add a counter that displays to screen that shows how many bg where (when & is at the end of the line), but I don't know why it's not working. Now I'm trying this but it doesn't work either, maybe I should modify the value in the parent process? This it the code:

```
void execute(char **tokens, int token_Size, int *blk){
pid_t pid, wpid;
int status;
int result;

int flag;

int isPipe;
int output;
int input;

int isAmper;
pid = fork();
if (pid == -1)
{
    perror("Fork:");
    exit(1);
}
else if (pid == 0)
{
    isAmper = needs_amper(tokens, token_Size);
    output = needs_out_redir(tokens, token_Size);
    input = needs_in_redir(tokens, token_Size);
    isPipe = needs_pipe(tokens, token_Size);
    static int bloq = 1;

    if (isAmper != -1)
    {
        *blk +=1;
        printf("[%d] %d \n", *blk, getppid()); //-> [blk] is the job number asigned to the job
        tokens[isAmper] = NULL;
    }

    if (strcmp(tokens[0], "echo") == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; tokens[i]; i++)
        {
            printf("%s ", tokens[i]);
        }
    }

    flag = 0;

    if (output != -1)
    {
        redirect_output(tokens, output);
        tokens[output] = NULL;
        flag = 1;
    }

    if (input != -1)
    {
        redirect_input(tokens, input);
        tokens[input] = NULL;
        flag = 1;
    }

    if (isPipe != -1)
    {
        create_pipe(tokens, output, input, isPipe);
    }

    if (flag || isPipe == -1)
    {
        execvp(tokens[0], tokens);
        perror("Unkown Command:");
        exit(1);
    }

    //  exit(0);
}
else // Main (parent) process after fork succeeds
{
    
    while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0)
        ; // this way, the father waits for all the child processes

    result = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    if (result == 1) //If the process terminated correctly, result returns 0.
    {
        printf("The child process terminated with an error!.\n");
    }
}}
```

I'm trying to modify the **blk** value passed to the execute function, I tried using an inside value also, but doesnt work either.
To make my self clearer. I want that when I type in my custom shell something with an '&' at the end it return something like this:

> ivo@ivo-Surface-Pro-6:/home/ivo/Documents/SO1/soi-myshell-Ivoo25$ echo hola &

> [1] 10853

> hola

And the next time I type something with the & at the end..

> [2] 10853

> main.c  main.o  Makefile  myshell  myShell.c  myShell.h  myShell.o  README.md

I think that what Im trying to do cant be done because the pid is the same in every execution, maybe is that?

Comment: "maybe I should modify the value in the parent process". That would be more likely to work. Incrementing `blk` in the child process definetely won't work as that is private to the child, does not change the parent's value and hence does not get passed on to the next child.

Comment: @kaylum The thing is I dont know, or cant figure out how to make it like that, I tried that when my variable 'isAmper' is a number increment it, but it does it even when I dont pass '&' to console

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it, I added the same function

```
needs_amper(tokens, token_Size)
```

but outside the child process, before the fork inside an if function veryfing that it returns a value higher than 0